# Inserting a html tag before an element using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a html document that is structured as following:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <span class="date">
        2021.
    </span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="date">
        2020.
    </span>
<span class="links">
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to insert a header inbetween the two entries depending on whether a condition is met using beautifulsoup but am only able to place it inside of the li tags:

```
current_date = None
for i,entry in enumerate(soup.findAll('li')):
    date = entry.find('span', {'class' : 'date'})
    item_date = date.text
    if item_date != current_date:
        current_date = item_date
        new_tag = soup.new_tag('h3', id='year_heading')
        new_tag.string = current_date
        entry.insert(0,new_tag)
```

the goal is to make it look as following:

```
<ul>
<h3 id="year_heading">2021</h3>
<li>
    <span class="date">
        2021.
    </span>
</li>
<h3 id="year_heading">2020</h3>
<li>
    <span class="date">
        2020.
    </span>
<span class="links">
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

but the current output is

```
<ul>
<li><h3 id="year_heading">2021</h3>
    <span class="date">
        2021.
    </span>
</li>

<li><h3 id="year_heading">2020</h3>
    <span class="date">
        2020.
    </span>
<span class="links">
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

this places my heading at the top of the li tag, resulting in an entry with the bulletpoint being placed beside the header instead of beside the entry itself. Is there a good solution to this problem?

EDIT: added desired output

Comment: I think it would be better if you showed your desired output HTML instead of just describing what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<ul>
<li>
    <span class="date">
        2021.
    </span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="date">
        2020.
    </span>
<span class="links">
</span>
</li>
</ul>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for span in soup.select("span.date"):
    txt = span.get_text(strip=True).strip(".")
    ul = span.find_parent("ul")
    ul.insert(
        ul.contents.index(span.find_parent("li")),
        BeautifulSoup(
            '<h3 id="year_heading">{}</h3>\n'.format(txt), "html.parser"
        ),
    )

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<ul>
<h3 id="year_heading">2021</h3>
<li>
<span class="date">
        2021.
    </span>
</li>
<h3 id="year_heading">2020</h3>
<li>
<span class="date">
        2020.
    </span>
<span class="links">
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```